# Outlook won't close - very strange behaviour

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently installed Outlook 2013 on my PC, and it works fine - except for the fact that it won't close. Now, I know this issue has been dealt with before, but this is different.

When I try to exit Outlook, it just won't close, as in - the window just stays open. No matter what I do. File > Exit, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, and the [x] button do nothing. When I look to see if it has frozen, the Task Manager is not reporting *any* issues. Outlook is still running fine, regardless of whether or not it is the only thing open. It *will* close if I "End Task", but it closes without any "Not Responding" errors.

I already checked the [list of Add-ins](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/close.asp#addins) that have affected Outlook closing (window closes, but process/service keeps running), but none of these are applicable (Add-ins not installed/enabled).

Comment: What OS you have?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Good job on looking at add-ons, as this is almost *always* the reason Outlook doesn't close normally. That said, what add-ons do you have installed? Consider posting a screen shot if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to run Outlook in safe mode: outlook.exe /safe

While running Outlook in safe mode, try to exit it. If succeeded, then the problem is in one or more installed add-ins. In this case, restart Outlook in normal mode and disable all add-ins. After that you can find the troublesome add-in by enabling add-ins one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the office repair, I find it works about 60% of the time.

Note: you may need to log in to register Office after it finishes so make sure you know your Microsoft Live ID or Office 365 credentials you are using before you start.

If you go to the old add remove programs, Start -> search for -> Control Pannel -> Uninstall a program -> Select Microsoft Office -> Select "Change" -> Online Repair

Thanks,

Mike